# htaccess rewrite rule with wildcards

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to create a htaccess file for my site.

I would like it so that when a user enters http://sitename.co.uk/category/productname/?pid=productID they are shown the page http://sitename.co.uk/product.php?id=productID

So the category and the productname are essentially wildcards and can be anything as the page is powered by the productID.

I have tried writing the following but have had no luck with it...

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(?pid=.*)$ product.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should can try like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) /product.php?id=%1
```

%1 is back-reference for RewriteCond. $1 is back-reference for RewriteRule.

Comment: worked perfectly...thanks very much. I struggle with all the htaccess rules

Answer (score 0):

You will need to capture value of `pid` parameter from a `RewriteCond` as `RewriteRule` doesn't match query:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?id=51 [L,NC,QSA]
```